# What is an Initial Token Offering?

Tags: terminology, cryptocurrency

1. Is it the same thing as an 'Initial Coin Offering'?
2. What would the a-z of such a thing look like in plain terms?

Comment: Yes, it is the same thing as the scam also referred to as an 'initial coin offering'.

Comment: Simply put, they take your money for worthless tokens, and then you can try to sell your worthless tokens to some other fool.

Answer (score 2):

Scott Adams (of *Dilbert* fame), in promoting his WhenHub App and WHEN Tokens ITO, explains the difference between digital “coins” and digital “tokens” in a recent [blog post](http://blog.dilbert.com/2018/03/26/say-hello-to-the-whenhub-interface-app-and-our-public-ico-ito/):

> For legal reasons, and to avoid the regulatory burden of being an “investment” vehicle, WhenHub and others use the word token instead of coin, although in casual use the terms are (incorrectly) often conflated as one.

Essentially they are the same thing. But companies (including WhenHub) that call their newly created cryptocurrency “tokens” instead of “coins” are trying to emphasize that their purpose is to create a currency for use in their specific app and not trying to create a new general use currency for investment purposes (although in the future they will be traded on exchanges and may be used for more than just one app).